# Player not moving towards target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I'm doing a course from udemy on Unity Game Development. I'm learning core combat and in it there's a section i'm stuck at in which the player has to move towards the target for combat when the target is clicked. It is also desired to stop before the target 2 meters away.

I have tried literally everything and I cannot find the error in my code. Please help me in finding the error and make this working. I really need assisstance.

**Mover.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using RPG.Combat;
using RPG.Core;

namespace RPG.Movement
{
    public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform target;

        void Update()
        {
            UpdateAnimator();
        }

        public void StartMoveAction(Vector3 destination)
        {
            // GetComponent<ActionScheduler>().StartAction(this);
            // GetComponent<Fighter>().Cancel();
            // MoveTo(destination);
            ActionScheduler actionScheduler = GetComponent<ActionScheduler>();
            if (actionScheduler != null)
            {
                actionScheduler.StartAction(this);
            }

            Fighter fighter = GetComponent<Fighter>();
            if (fighter != null)
            {
                fighter.Cancel();
            }

            if (destination != null)
            {
                MoveTo(destination);
            }
        }

        public void MoveTo(Vector3 destination)
        {
            GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().destination = destination;
            GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().isStopped = false;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().isStopped = true;
        }

        private void UpdateAnimator()
        {
            Vector3 velocity = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().velocity;
            Vector3 localVelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(velocity);
            float speed = localVelocity.z;
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("ForwardSpeed", speed);
        }
    }
}
```

**PlayerController.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using RPG.Movement;
using RPG.Combat;

namespace RPG.Control
{
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Update()
        {
            if (InteractWithCombat()) return;
            if (InteractWithMovement()) return;
        }

        private bool InteractWithCombat()
        {
            RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(GetMouseRay());

            foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)
            {
               CombatTarget target1 = hit.transform.GetComponent<CombatTarget>();

                if (target1 == null) continue;

                if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                    GetComponent<Fighter>().Attack(target1);
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool InteractWithMovement()
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            bool hasHit = Physics.Raycast(GetMouseRay(), out hit);

            if (hasHit)
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                {
                    GetComponent<Mover>().StartMoveAction(hit.point);
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private static Ray GetMouseRay()
        {
            return Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fighter.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using RPG.Combat;
using RPG.Movement;
using RPG.Core;
using RPG.Control;

namespace RPG.Combat
{
    public class Fighter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] float weaponRange = 2f;        
        Transform target;

        private void Update()
        {
            if (target == null) return;

            bool isInRange = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) < weaponRange;

            if (!isInRange)
            {
                GetComponent<Mover>().MoveTo(target.position);
            }
            else
            {
                GetComponent<Mover>().Stop();
            }
        }

        public void Attack(CombatTarget combatTarget)
        {
            ActionScheduler actionScheduler = GetComponent<ActionScheduler>();

            if (actionScheduler != null)
            {
               actionScheduler.StartAction(this);
            }

            target = combatTarget.transform;
        }

        public void Cancel()
        {
            target = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**CombatTarget.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace RPG.Combat
{
    public class CombatTarget : MonoBehaviour
    {

    }
}
```

**ActionScheduler.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

namespace RPG.Core 
{
   public class ActionScheduler : MonoBehaviour
   {
     MonoBehaviour currentAction;

     public void StartAction(MonoBehaviour action)
     {
        if(currentAction == action) return;

        if(currentAction != null)
        {
            print("Cancelling" + currentAction);
        }

        currentAction = action;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: It would be arguably more sensible to ask on the q&a on the course. However. By the looks of it has to so with your navmesh

Comment: In general you do a lot of redundant work there. Why raycasting twice for instance? simply use the `RaycastAll` results also for the other method .. store the references returned by `GetComponent`! Is it possible that your `Fighter` script was not `Cancel`ed so it still tries to reach a previous target?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).